# SQL query populate many relationship as a field with array type with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have the following tables:

Students

```
ID --- Name
A --- Andy
B --- Billy
C --- Chris
```

Score

```
StudentID  --- Subject --- Score
A --- Math --- 6
A --- English --- 5
B --- Math --- 8
B --- English--- 5
C --- Math --- 1
C --- English --- 4
```

Then I want to query students who has at least 1 score === 5, and also populate all the score of them.

In the example above, I want this result

```
[
  {
    id: "A",
    name: "Andy",
    scores: [
      {
         subject: "Math",
         score: 6
      },
      {
         subject: "English",
         score: 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "B",
    name: "Billy",
    scores: [
      {
         subject: "Math",
         score: 8
      },
      {
         subject: "English",
         score: 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to know how ORM query this result in Raw SQL query (SELECT FROM WHERE). I appreciate any helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `MAX(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID)` in CTE.

Comment: thanks for reply, I've updated my question, how the query will be if the condition is not greater/lower than operator, I mean that it's a condition we need to perform a subquery to achieve.

Comment: If so use `SUM(Score = 5) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID)` in CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what result you want.  But the idea is `JOIN` and aggregation:

```
select s.id, s.name,
       group_concat(sc.subject, ':', score) as subject_scores
from students s join
     scores sc
     on s.id = sc.studentid
group by s.id, s.name
having sum(sc.score = 5) > 0;
```

Or if `5` is the maximum score, then:

```
having sum(sc.score) = 5
```

If you want a result set in JSON, then obviously you would use JSON functions instead of string functions.

Comment: Thanks for reply, if the condition is not simply greater than operator then how can we query it, I've updated my question, please take a look. thanks

Comment: @QuocVanTang `HAVING SUM(sc.score=5);`